# Scala Calculate averages dataframe from column contains date and defined dates periods

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

how to calculate averages of one column contain values from different time intervals from a date which is other column "Date", conditions; groupby "Client" and "Article" then calculate average for both combined for a time range, - 7 days and + 15 days, calculated both form column "Date"

table

```
 "Date"     "Client"    "Article"   "Value"     
20190101    163356418   10629186    29.82
20190101    163356418   11732013    0
20190101    150494662   11791020    164.21895
20190101    150494662   23200       143.64755
20190101    150494662   23227       152.172
```

4 new columns are expected as output, two for calculate dates(-7 and +15) and two for their corresponding averages ("Average Value - 7 days" , "Average Value +15 days"), not sure how to define the time periods, using df with column to create the new columns

```
 "Date"     "Client"    "Article"   "Value"     "Date - 7 days" "Average Value - 7 days"    "Date + 15 days"    "Average Value +15 days"
20190101    163356418   10629186    29.82
20190101    163356418   11732013    0
20190101    150494662   11791020    164.21895
20190101    150494662   23200       143.64755
20190101    150494662   23227       152.172
```

Code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df1 = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("s3a://tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/Cleartablet.csv")

val df2 = df1.groupBy("Client","Article)
    .agg(avg("Value")).withColumn("Average Value - 7 days", $"Average Value + 15 days")
    .show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the date into an integer date difference relative to the earliest date, and use a `rangeBetween` window to do average over -7 days or +15 days. To add/subtract days, use `date_add`.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df1 = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("s3a://tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/Cleartablet.csv")

val df2 = df1.withColumn(
    "Date",
    to_date($"Date".cast("string"), "yyyyMMdd")
).withColumn(
    "DateSinceBegin",
    datediff($"Date", min($"Date").over(Window.partitionBy("Client", "Article")))
).withColumn(
    "Date-7days",
    date_add($"Date", -7)
).withColumn(
    "AverageValue-7days",
    avg($"Value").over(Window.partitionBy("Client", "Article").orderBy("DateSinceBegin").rangeBetween(-7,0))
).withColumn(
    "Date+15days",
    date_add($"Date", 15)
).withColumn(
    "AverageValue+15days",
    avg($"Value").over(Window.partitionBy("Client", "Article").orderBy("DateSinceBegin").rangeBetween(0,15))
)

df2.show
+----------+---------+--------+---------+--------------+----------+------------------+-----------+-------------------+
|      Date|   Client| Article|    Value|DateSinceBegin|Date-7days|AverageValue-7days|Date+15days|AverageValue+15days|
+----------+---------+--------+---------+--------------+----------+------------------+-----------+-------------------+
|2019-01-01|150494662|   23227|  152.172|             0|2018-12-25|           152.172| 2019-01-16|            152.172|
|2019-01-01|150494662|11791020|164.21895|             0|2018-12-25|         164.21895| 2019-01-16|          164.21895|
|2019-01-01|150494662|   23200|143.64755|             0|2018-12-25|         143.64755| 2019-01-16|          143.64755|
|2019-01-01|163356418|10629186|    29.82|             0|2018-12-25|             29.82| 2019-01-16|              29.82|
|2019-01-01|163356418|11732013|      0.0|             0|2018-12-25|               0.0| 2019-01-16|                0.0|
+----------+---------+--------+---------+--------------+----------+------------------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Comment: hi, that's great, what DateSinceBegin column represents? can be hide?

Comment: @JohnChen Yes you can hide it using `val df3 = df2.drop("DateSinceBegin")`. It represents the date since the earliest date.

Comment: ok, how to not include the average of each row? I mean if there is not purchase before or after meaning there were not previous or futures purchases respectively from day 0 then average is 0 since there are not more purchases from this client before and or after

Comment: @JohnChen it should be included in my code already. average will be 0 if there are no 
 purchases within the window.

Comment: thanks mck, I accepted already the answer but cant see the update for not to include average like you mentioned

Comment: maybe I misunderstood. if you want to exclude rows with 0 average, then `filter` the dataframe. e.g. `val df3 = df2.filter($"AverageValue-7days" =!= 0)`

Comment: no, no. not exclude. Just the column average for - 7 days and + 15 days, should show average per both customer and article, for last 7 days and next 15 days not including the current row "Value", since you want to know what he has purchased before and what purchased after all calculated from "Date" which is in the current row

Comment: In case he hasn't purchased something before or after should be always 0

Comment: Oh, if you don't want to include current row, then replace `rangeBetween(-7,0)` with `rangeBetween(-7,-1)` and `rangeBetween(0,15)` with `rangeBetween(1,15)`